# Checking Time to allow form filling in PHP (and javascript)

Tags: php, javascript

For a website, we have a form where a client enters in their ID number that sends them to a new page that allows them to make a request for our services.

We want to change it so that clients can only request our services from Tuesday-Friday from 12pm - 4pm. If they try to enter their id number during a time outside of Tuesday-Friday from 12pm - 4pm, it will tell them they cannot request our services.

What I want to do is that if the user accesses the page during times when they **cannot** make a request, an alert box (through javascript) will pop up telling them that. I also want to code something so that if they try to progres forward (clicking the create request button), they will not (though php).

I'm not sure how to check these times with PHP and Javascript in order to accomplish this. If anyone has any insight in how to do this, that would be fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: I assume the local servers timezone will suffice? Or does this need to function per end-users time-zone?

Comment: Just the local server timezone is required.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<?PHP
$dayOfWeek = date("w");
$currentHour = date("G");

if ($dayOfWeek >= 2 && $dayOfWeek <= 5 && $currentHour >= 12 && $currentHour <= 16) {
  // Show Form
}
else {
    ?>
    <script>alert('Form only available Tuesday - Friday, 12:00pm to 4:00pm');</script>
    <?PHP
}
?>
```

For more information on PHP's date function, see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

"G" = 24 hour format without leading 0's

"w" = Day of week, 0 = Sunday, 6 = Saturday

Comment: That will fix the time when the user requests the page, which will be a different time to when it's submitted. I don't know which the OP wants, but likely it's when the form is submitted that matters.

Comment: When the user requests the page is fine. On the form, all they need to do is enter their id number and it will take them to the next page.
I will take a look tomorrow to see if what you proposed works. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to check when the page is requested, then there is no need for client side script at all. Check at the server when the page is requested and either return a form for them to enter their ID, or a message advising the service is not available and when it will be.